# ignore a main in a header file

Tags: c++, pragma, redefinition

I'm trying to use ([Ligra](https://github.com/jshun/ligra)) in a project. The framework works as long as the chief header "ligra.h" is included. Trouble is, that header has an implementation of `parallel_main`, which is a macro wrapper around `main` with `OpenMP` trickery. So if I wanted to write a simple program:

```
#include "ligra.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
std::cout<<"Hello World";
return 0;
}
```

It would not compile. Redefinition of symbol `main`.

Also, I need a `parallel_main`, with the exact macro trickery done in the `"parallel.h"` header.

So  I think I have two options:

1) modify the file, add a pair of `#ifdef LIGRA_MAIN`'s and not define the macro at compile time. Thus I can have my own `main` and not have redefinition. Trouble is I need my project to be using the upstream version of ligra, and Julian Shun, the original developer has probably forgottten about his project (and github, since he ignored more than one pull request).

2) Use/Write a `#pragma` that would strip that function out at the include stage.

I don't know how to do that last part, and would be very much in your debt if someone who did, reached out.

Comment: It's a macro, that is either an `OpenMP` or `CILK` version of `main` for parallelism.

Comment: just use the same dirty trick and enclose the header in a `#define main ax123123123`  / `#undef main`

Comment: That is a dirty fix indeed. I'd then be hardcoding the type of parallelism framework and lose the "flexibility" that ligra had. @user463035818

Comment: not sure if I understood correctly, you need to include the header, but you want to "exclude" the main, right?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. @user463035818. to be more precise, I want to be able to redefine `parallel_main` in a file outside the header. What you offer is pretty close to what I want, but not exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that does not involve modifying library files (but is somewhat brittle) could be to do the following:

1. `#include "ligra/parallel.h"` (this does `#define parallel_main main`).
2. `#undef parallel_main` to prevent this rewriting of function names.
3. `#include "ligra/ligra.h"` as usual. Since `parallel.h` has an include guard, its repeated inclusion is prevented and `parallel_main` will not be redefined.
4. Proceed as normal.

You might also want to wrap this into a header so you only have to write it once.

Alternatively, you could do what @user463035818 suggests and redefine `main` only for the inclusion of `ligra.h` for very similar effect. The difference is in the names that the `parallel_main` function(s) from ligra will get.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply not include ligra.h. If there is something useful in that file, then create a copy of the file - excluding the main function - and use that copy.

Sure, that means that if the upstream ligra.h is updated, your copy will not have the corresponding changes. However, given the premise *"the original developer has probably forgottten about his project"*, this is probably not a problem. If the premise is wrong, then a better approach would be to create a pull request to make the framework usable as a library.